# Include node name in console log output

Tags: ros, roslaunch, rosout, logging

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is there any way to include the node name (or PID) in the console log output from running roslaunch? It's often hard to tell which messages come from which nodes.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/243374/include-node-name-in-console-log-output/) by [mrjogo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1576/mrjogo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 164 on 2016-09-08

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [DavidN](https://answers.ros.org/users/26292/davidn/) on 2016-09-08**:
If you are the author of the node (or having the source code of the node), it is good to follow some good habit of using ros log includind add node name into the log. Take a look at this http://answers.ros.org/question/30908/determine-a-nodes-namenamespace-from-within-the-node-c/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

See [wiki/rosconsole - Console Output Formatting](http://wiki.ros.org/rosconsole#Console_Output_Formatting).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-09-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2